# Combinatoric Proof of $\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n}{j} = \sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n-1-j}{k-j}2^j$

Tags: combinatorics

For a binary string of length $n$ that has at most $k$ $1$'s, it makes complete sense that the total number of possibilities is 
$\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n}{j}$. But I am struggling to wrap my head around 
$\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n-1-j}{k-j}2^j$ being an equivalent way of counting. I can see where the $2^j$ comes from but I can't quite see the $n-1-j$ part. Can someone could give me some guidance on what that method of counting is actually saying?

Comment: When $k=n$, this should give you $2^n$. But the second expressions gives $0$ in that case, because $n-j > n-j-1$. There must be some problem somewhere.

Comment: I think you're right about the problem, but this is how it was given to me. Do you have any idea as to what it was supposed to be?

Comment: Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3183180/177399. The equation is true only when $k<n$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest  Thank you for linking this! It makes complete sense now